# R ggplot color bin widths appear unequal

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Hello I am ploting a graph which will have the legend,width of legend items not same can any one help me to resolve my problem

data file

< [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EKhRwup3vUC3KVFOOh4XtKERIr8FQj3x/view?usp=sharing>](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EKhRwup3vUC3KVFOOh4XtKERIr8FQj3x/view?usp=sharing%3E)

code I have used

```
df=read.table("test.txt",sep='\t', header=TRUE)
df = data.frame(df)
nCol <- 15
myCol <- viridis(n = nCol)
myCol
ggplot(df, aes(log(data1), log(data2),color=data3),cex=1.9)+
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_stepsn(colours = c(myCol),breaks = seq(0,100,by=10))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 12, face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 7, face="bold"), legend.position="top",
        legend.key.size = unit(10, "mm"),
        legend.key.width=unit(10, "mm"))
```

at the end of legend 90-100 width is high compare to others

Comment: I see that you have reverted the edits I made on your post. These were intended to make the question easier to understand and to demonstrate the problem more clearly since it had already received a close vote. Was there a specific reason you reverted these edits?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of asides before addressing your main concern:

- You can simplify your code by using `scale_color_binned(type = "viridis")`, which gives the same result as creating a vector of
  viridis colors and interpolating them as you are doing, with the added advantage that you don't need to load the `viridis` library.
- You can use log scales on the x and y axis without having to transform your
  data, by using `scale_x_log10()` and `scale_y_log10()`
- You can simplify your `theme` call by first calling `theme_classic()`, which gets rid of the need to specify all those `element_blank()` components.

For the specific problem that you encountered though, the reason for the appearance is that `breaks` are for the "internal" breaks of the binned scale. The outer edges of your scale are not *breaks*, but *limits*. By default, limits are not shown on binned scales, but you can turn them on using `show.limits = TRUE` after setting the limits to the desired value of `c(0, 100)`

So your above code can be rewritten as:

```r
df <- read.table("test.txt", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)

ggplot(df, aes(log(data1), log(data2), color = data3), cex = 1.9) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_binned(type        = "viridis", 
                      breaks      = 1:9 * 10, 
                      limits      = c(0, 100),
                      show.limits = TRUE, 
                      labels      = function(x) round(x)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(text            = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
        legend.text     = element_text(size = 7,  face = "bold"), 
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.key.size = unit(10, "mm"))
```

[image]

Comment: why the scale of the X and Y axis not in the log values

Comment: @Hemantchandrunaik I changed them for clarity. You can change them back if you prefer. Would you like me to do that?

Comment: its okay I changed, 90-10 there are lot of values is it possible break on that perticular bin 90-92,92-94...98-100 like that bin